# Workflow Max add job via API

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to add a job to the Workflow Max API. I seem to be hitting the API but I keep getting the error message:

```
Message not in expected format.  The following required element was missing - Job/ClientID
```

I'm sure that the client ID is added but something seems to be wrong. This is the code:

```
function post_job_to_workflow_max($job_data) {

    // configure our connection to the api
    $api_token = 'API_KEY';
    $acc_key = 'ACC_TOKEN';
    $url = 'https://api.workflowmax.com/job.api/add?apiKey=' . $api_token . '&accountKey=' . $acc_key;

    // Job data must match the format required by WorkflowMax
    // currently accepts XML data
    // see: https://www.workflowmax.com/api/job-methods#POST%20add
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<Job></Job>");
    $xml->addChild('Name', $job_data[0]);
    $xml->addChild('Description', $job_data[1]);
    $xml->addChild('ClientID', 18754031);
    // $clientID = $xml->addChild('Client');
    // $clientID->addChild('ID', 18754031);
    // $clientID->addChild('Name', "TEST CLIENT");
    $xml->addChild('State', 'Planned');
    $xml->addChild('StartDate', $job_data[2]);
    $xml->addChild('DueDate', $job_data[3]);

    // print_r($xml);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml->asXML());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml->asXML()))
    );   
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = simplexml_load_string($output);
    print_r($result);

}
```

If there's anyone with experience of using WFM, would be good to hear how you approached it.

Thanks

Comment: Ryan, did you figure this out? I'm looking thru your code and can't seem to find anything that's different from the way I did it.

Comment: Yes, see my own answer below.

Answer (score 2):

So in answer to my own question, I did finally work this out.

The way I did this was to return the ID of the client from the function I used to post a client to WorkFlow Max. See code:

1) post the client

```
function post_client_to_workflowmax($client_data) {

        // configure our connection to the api
        $api_token = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
        $acc_key = 'YOUR_KEY';
        $url = 'https://api.workflowmax.com/client.api/add?apiKey=' . $api_token . '&accountKey=' . $acc_key;

        // Client data must match the format required by WorkflowMax
        // currently accepts XML data
        // These indexes match up with how the data has been stored
        // see: https://www.workflowmax.com/api/client-methods#POST%20add

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<Client></Client>");
        $xml->addChild('Name', htmlspecialchars($client_data[2]));
        $xml->addChild('Email', htmlspecialchars($client_data[9]));
        $xml->addChild('Phone', htmlspecialchars($client_data[10]));
        $xml->addChild('Address', htmlspecialchars($client_data[3]) . ' ' . htmlspecialchars($client_data[4]));
        $xml->addChild('City', htmlspecialchars($client_data[5]));
        $xml->addChild('Postcode', htmlspecialchars($client_data[7]));
        $xml->addChild('Country', htmlspecialchars($client_data[8]));
        $xml->addChild('IsProspect', 'No');
        $contacts = $xml->addChild('Contacts');
        $contact = $contacts->addChild('Contact');
        $name = $contact->addChild('Name', htmlspecialchars($client_data[0]) . ' ' . htmlspecialchars($client_data[1]));


        // POST request
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml->asXML());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml->asXML()))
        );
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // Create an array from the data that is sent back from the API
        $result = simplexml_load_string($output);
        $clientID = NULL;
        // here we get the ID created for this client and pass it into the variable $clientID
        foreach($result->Client as $k => $v) {
                $clientID = $v->ID;
        }
        return $clientID;
}
```

We then get that ID passed into our job posting function like so:

2) post a job to WFM

```
function post_job_to_workflow_max($job_data, $clientID) {

        // configure our connection to the api
        $api_token = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
        $acc_key = 'YOUR_KEY';
        $url = 'https://api.workflowmax.com/job.api/add?apiKey=' . $api_token . '&accountKey=' . $acc_key;

        // Job data must match the format required by WorkflowMax
        // currently accepts XML data
        // see: https://www.workflowmax.com/api/job-methods#POST%20add
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<Job></Job>");
        $xml->addChild('ClientID', $clientID);
        $xml->addChild('Name', htmlspecialchars($job_data[0]));
        $xml->addChild('Description', htmlspecialchars($job_data[1]));
        $xml->addChild('State', 'Planned');
        $xml->addChild('StartDate', htmlspecialchars($job_data[2]));
        $xml->addChild('DueDate', htmlspecialchars($job_data[3]));

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml->asXML());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml->asXML()))
        );
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $result = simplexml_load_string($output);

}
```

And then calling these functions looks something like this:

```
$id = post_client_to_workflowmax($client);
post_job_to_workflow_max($job, $id);
```

Where $client must be an array of data. This worked for my case but might not work for your particular case so you may need to edit the fields etc.

Hopefully this helps someone who is stuck with the same problem. Not the most elegant code but it gets the job done.

Comment: Did you get this working correctly? I'm working ok with the Xero API but struggling to understand how to get the WFM connection. The API docs aren't as good as the Xero ones it seems.